# Incrementing the element name using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have this jQuery script responsible for adding new tutorial (by adding a new table row) if a button is clicked. A new row will then be added on a table with select drop down and a text box for user to enter its information:

```
    $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
    var num     = $('.clonedInput').length;        
    var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);

    var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);        

    newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);
    $('#input' + num).after(newElem);        
    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','');

});
```

This is the HTML markup:

```
<table class="widefat">
<thead>
<tr>    
<th style="width: 2.5%;"></th>
<th style="width: 2.5%;"></th>                          

<th style="width: 50%;">Subject</th>                            
<th>Delay in days</th>
<th style="width: 15%;">Send e-mail</th>
  </tr>

  </thead>  

  <tbody id="sortableinputs" class="ui-sortable">               
  <tr class="clonedInput" id="input1">

<td width="2.5%">Drag this</td>                        

    <td width="2.5%">Delete this row</td>                                 

<td width="50%">                    

                <select style="width:100%;" name="group_tutorial_posts1">
            <option value="551">This is a tutorial title</option>       
            <option value="552">This is another tutorial title</option>         

        </select>

</td>

<td><input type="text" name="name1">Period</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Send email" class="button-secondary"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>                  


</table>
```

My problem is that how could I revise my jQuery script such that increment would match with my select name and text box name as well.

For example, if I click the button the tr id will be input 2(no problem on this, the jQuery script is working fine about this)

```
<tr class="clonedInput" id="input2">
```

But I would also like (this is my problem) the select name and text name to increment as well, so it will become:

```
<select style="width:100%;" name="group_tutorial_posts2">
```

and:

```
<input type="text" name="name2">
```

If add another:

```
<select style="width:100%;" name="group_tutorial_posts3">
<input type="text" name="name3">
```

for incremented tr of:

```
<tr class="clonedInput" id="input3">
```

I have added a very simplified JS fidde demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/codex_meridian/dP5xZ/2/

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Given the code you already have, something along the lines of:

This code would go in where you add a new tr. A little verbose, I'm sure there are shorter more eloquent ways. But you'd just follow same for the subsquent input field.

```
    var _tr =  $('#sortableinputs tr:last');
        _tr.attr('name','group_tutorial_posts' + _tr.index());
        _tr.find(':first > select').attr('name',_tr.attr('name'));
```